# How to use a float in inequalities

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hi my code is giving me the following error:

```
Error:(116, 23) java: method isPulled in class com.testrr.pizzadeliverymadness.Lever cannot 
be applied to given types;
  required: float
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Here is the part of the if statement that is causing all the trouble:

```
chefY > 0f
```

`chefY` is a `float` (I guess?), I got it from using a sprites Y position:

Here is the code I use to set `chefY`:

```
chefY = Boyardee.getY();
```

I dont know why I get this error, can someone look at it?

EDIT: Here is the whole `Lever` class:

```
package com.zacharyweiss.pizzadeliverymadness;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

/**
 * Created by zachw on 10/25/15.
 */
public class Lever extends Button {
    public Lever (Texture texture) {super(texture);}

    public boolean isPulled(float chefY) {

        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()
           && Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY() >= this.getY() 
           && this.getHeight() <= this.getY() + this.getHeight()
           && this.getWidth() >= Gdx.input.getX() && chefY > 0f)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The function is called by a simple if statement

```
if (GreenLever.isPulled()) {
    Boyardee.setTexture(new Texture("Photos/ChefGreen.png"));
}
```

I have now gotten a NullPointerException which is as follows:

```
   2015-11-01 20:46:15.018 java[3455:235609] 20:46:15.018 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.zacharyweiss.pizzadeliverymadness.InGameScreen.<init>(InGameScreen.java:34)
    at com.zacharyweiss.pizzadeliverymadness.PizzaDeliveryMadness.create(PizzaDeliveryMadness.java:67)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Comment: where is the class and where is isPulled method? give more code

Comment: @JonnyHenly I added more code

Comment: @KalpeshSoni I added more code

Comment: and more of calling code?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni added it

Comment: GreenLever.isPulled() - who will pass the argument that it requires?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni it wasnt being passed in, I havent used functions with stuff you need to pass in alot, I ran it... but i got a different error, I got a NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

You have written `isPulled()` so that it requires a `float` as a parameter. When you try to call it, you pass no arguments to it. Instead of:

```
if (greenLever.isPulled())
```

which passes no arguments to `isPulled()`, do something like this:

```
float x = //whatever you want it to equal
if (greenLever.isPulled(x) {
    Boyardee.setTexture(new Texture("Photos/ChefGreen.png"));
}
```

Comment: yeah that's where the problem is

Comment: Have you initialized `greenLever` object?

Comment: @user3391113 ok, post the `Exception`.

Comment: Have you initialized `x` (or whatever you're using in its place)?

Comment: @BethanyLouise yes `float x = Boyardee.getY();`

Comment: Are you getting the NullPointerException at the same line of code as the previous error?

Comment: @camelCaseCoder I posted the exception

Comment: @BethanyLouise no, it is at a new place

Comment: What is at `InGameScreen.java` line number 34?

Comment: @camelCaseCoder `InGameScreen.java` line 34 is `x= Boyardee.getY();`

Comment: So probably `Boyardee` object is not initialized. (BTW always start an object with a small case letter)

Comment: Replace `x = Boyardee.getY();` with `System.out.println(Boyardee.getY();`. If it still returns the same error, it's likely `Boyardee` has not actually been initialized.

Comment: @BethanyLouise so my code now works!! It is constantly printing the Y pos... but it works!!

Comment: @BethanyLouise I just realized i was setting that variable, before the constructor..